# Medians which lie in sequence of even length.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations, median

Given a sequence of numbers say `[1,2,2,2,4,3,3]` from this sequence how many sub-sequences in order can be formed in which the median will lie in the sub-sequences itself. I have found that for all sequences of odd length it will hold true. Therefore total number of sequences with odd length are `nC1+nC3+nC5+...+nCn` for current array n=7. Now I have also figured out that all the sequences of length 2 which can be formed are `3C2 + 2C2` i.e `C(3,2) + C(2,2)` That is it will be only possible if we have both the same in above example it will be `[2,2] [2,2] [2,2] [3,3]` the elements will be treated different if they are at different indices in sequence. How I will find number of other sequences of length 4,6... and other even length sequences.

Comment: Can you clarify? When you say "in order", do you mean that the subsequences must be non-decreasing? Or just that the indices of the elements must be increasing?

Comment: I mean to say that the in the sub-sequence the order in which number are present should be followed that is for a sub-sequence Ai,Aj,Ak,Al...., 1<=i<j<k<l<.. and so on where i,j,k,l are positions of numbers in original sequence.

Comment: This problem was taken from a [contest](https://www.codechef.com/NOV18B/problems/GMEDIAN) that closed 12 November 2018.

Answer (score 2):

Reposing the answer now that the contest has ended

---

First note that the problem does not change if we first sort the sequence. So the number of subsequences that contain its own median in the sequence $[1,2,2,2,4,3,3]$ is the same as that of $[1,2,2,2,3,3,4]$.

Suppose that we had a (sorted) even length subsequence $a_1,...,a_{2n}$ that contained its own median. Then the elements $a_{n}$ and $a_{n+1}$ must be equal. As in your post, you identified that the possibilities in your example for the elements $a_{n}$ and $a_{n+1}$ were $[2,2]$ (with multiplicity $3$) and $[3,3]$. The only possibilities for the median are those elements that appear multiple times in the array.

For an even length subsequence $a_n$, let the possible medians be the set $\text{med}(a_n)$. For any element $a$ in the sequence, let $l(a)$ be the number of elements in the sequence less than $a$ and let $g(a)$ be the number of elements in the sequence greater than $a$. To construct a subsequence from a given $m\in \text{med}(a_n)$, then for some $k\le g(m), l(m)$, select $k$ elements that are less than $m$ and $k$ elements that are greater than $m$, and add them to the subsequence. The number of ways to do this is
$$
\sum_{m\in \text{med}(a_n)}\left( 
\sum^{min\{g(m),l(m)\}}_{i=0}\binom{g(m)}{i}\binom{l(m)}{i} 
\right)
$$
However, this solution has a major issue. It assumes that there are always exactly $2$ elements in the subsequence equal to the median $m$. There must be at least $2$, but there could be more. Consider the subsequence $[1,2,2,2]$ from the example sequence. To fix this issue, let $n(m)$ be the multiplicity of $m\in \text{med}(a_n)$,
$$
\sum_{m\in \text{med}(a_n)}\left(
\sum^{(n(m)-2)}_{x=0} 
\sum^{(n(m)-2-x)}_{y=0}
\left(
\sum^{min\{g(m)+x,l(m)+y\}}_{i=0}\binom{g(m)+x}{i}\binom{l(m)+y}{i} 
\right) 
\right)
$$
Using Vandermonde's identity, we can simplify the innermost sum,
$$
\sum_{m\in \text{med}(a_n)}\left(
\sum^{(n(m)-2)}_{x=0} 
\sum^{(n(m)-2-x)}_{y=0}
\binom{(g(m)+x)+(l(m)+y)}{(g(m)+x)} 
\right)
$$
This equals the number of even length subsequences that contain their own median.