# Given a sequence find sub-sequence that satisfy given condition

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have a sequence like `A B C D E F G H I J`
I am finding total sub-sequences of even length such that they always have mid elements from index (4 to 6) ie. `D` to `F` assuming 1 based indexing.

So my approach is :

For  `D E` to be mid element: $\binom{3}{1}$ $\binom{5}{1}$ + $\binom{3}{2}$ $\binom{5}{2}$ +$\binom{3}{3}$ $\binom{5}{3}$, as we can choose 1,2,3 elements from `A B C` and simultaneously 1,2,3 elements from `F G H I J`.

Similarly, for pair `E F` to be mid element : $\binom{4}{1}$ $\binom{4}{1}$ + $\binom{4}{2}$ $\binom{4}{2}$+ $\binom{4}{3}$ $\binom{4}{3}$ + $\binom{4}{4}$ $\binom{4}{4}$

Similarly, for pair `D F` to be mid element: $\binom{3}{1}$ $\binom{4}{1}$+$\binom{3}{2}$ $\binom{4}{2}$+$\binom{3}{3}$ $\binom{4}{3}$

Clearly answer will be sum of above terms.Can this result be generalised for a sequence of length `n` and `i` and `j` where `i` and `j` are start and end indices from where we choose the middle two elements?

Answer (score 1):

First, your counting seems to forget the subsequences $[D,E]$, $[E,F]$, and $[D,F]$. The terms $\binom{3}{0}\binom{5}{0}$, $\binom{4}{0}\binom{4}{0}$, and $\binom{3}{0}\binom{4}{0}$ have been omitted.

This problem seems to be similar to the problem ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986089/medians-which-lie-in-sequence-of-even-length?noredirect=1#comment6162469_2986089)) I answered a minute ago, but with slightly different phrasing and constraints.

Making the appropriate changes:

$$
\sum^{(j-i-1)}_{x=0} 
\sum^{(j-i-1-x)}_{y=0}
\binom{(n-j+x)+(i-1+y)}{(n-j+x)}
$$